# Combine two different post types into one table in Django

Tags: python, django, posts

I have two Models:-

> **tripbook**(id,country, state, place,detail,rating,experience,date)
>
> **album**(id,location, rating, experience, date)

How can I show both the tripbook and album at one place based on creation date.

For this I made one more table to store some details from both the tables as:

> **broadcast**(id, post_type, social_status, creation date, tripbook_id, album_id)

But this is not working for me as one of the foreign key will be blank from `tripbook_id` or `album_id`.

If any other database structure can help then suggest it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please be a bit more descriptive in what you are trying to do. You can use something like `tripbook.objects.filter(date=datetime.date(2014,3,13))` to retrieve items from a particular date. If you are trying to link tripbooks and albums, I'd suggest a foreign key relationship from one to the other.